# Django CMS restrict view of placeholders/plugins for certain groups

Tags: django-cms

I was wondering if there's a django-cms builtin way to show/not show a placeholder or plugin for users, depending on their related group.

For example: I've got an ecommerce website, in the product page I want to show in a sidebar placeholder a special offers plugin just for users that are part of the 'subscribers' group, so users that aren't part of it will not see the plugin in the sidebar

Should I do that using making conditions in the template so that I show a different placeholder depending on the group, or there's a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your special offers plugin is a custom plugin that you have written, you could simply override the `render` method for the plugin.

```
class SpecialOffers(CMSPluginBase):
    ...

    def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
        context = super(SpecialOffers, self).render(context, instance, placeholder)
        # grab user from context
        request = context.get('request', None)
        user = request and request.user
        # check user related group condition
        context['show_special_offers'] = False
        if user and user.in_right_group():
            context['show_special_offers'] = True
        return context
```

Then, you can use the `show_special_offers` in the template for the special offers plugin, in order to determine if you should render the content of the special offers plugin.